# vim: replace a pattern which includes special characters and pattern spans across multiple lines

Tags: vim, replace, special-characters

I want to replace multiple stuffs:

My original file has:

```
<regSetting>
  <registerAddr>0x0112</registerAddr>
  <registerData>0x0A</registerData>
</regSetting>
<regSetting>
  <registerAddr>0x0113</registerAddr>
  <registerData>0x0A</registerData>
</regSetting>
```

I want to replace 3 items:

1st chunk:

```
<regSetting>
      <registerAddr>
```

to get:

```
reg_write(
```

2nd chunk:

```
</registerAddr>
<registerData>
```

To get:

```
,
```

3rd chunk:

```
</registerData>
</regSetting>
```

To get:

```
);
```

To finally get:

```
reg_write(0x0112, 0x0A);
reg_write(0x0113, 0x0A);
```

THis is easily replacable in if we use notepad++. Because there we have non-regex option where search can include new lines aswell, it can find all exact matches and replace.

I have tried in Vim, but vim substitution option works line by line. and I could not find appropriate answers.

This is one such requirement, and similarly I have multiple replacements to be done.
If its possible in Vim, I want to yank the chunk, and use it in below command (substitute)

```
%s/ctrl+"/new_word/g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can search and replace across multiple lines in vim, see [search across multiple lines](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Search_across_multiple_lines).

to accomplish your task you can use for example:

```
%s/^\s*<regSetting>\_s*<registerAddr>\(.*\)<\/registerAddr>\_s*<registerData>\(.*\)<\/registerData>\_s*<\/regSetting>/reg_write(\1, \2);/g
```

it's long, but I think *easy* to read. it basically matches the whole `<regSetting>` tag and content and captures the values, then substitutes the match using captured values.

the `\_s` pattern will match a whitespace (space or tab) or newline character.

Comment: I knew about ```\s*``` but not ```\_s*``` and ```\s*```  Can you provide some reference to search these regex options

Comment: Thanks this suited my usecase.  

If you can give hint on how to progress with visual selection involving multiple lines, yank and then search/replace  it would be helpful.

Comment: @ranjithkonaje the link I provided in the answer gives a nice explanation of `\_x` patterns, otherwise there is of course `:help \_s`, but I found it too terse. "visual selection multiple lines, yank and then search/replace" I'm not sure I understood your request correctly, you can paste yanked lines in the search "bar" using `ctrl+r 0`.